# is typedef type of derived type considered as derived type of a typedef type of corresponding base type

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code:

```
// Assumption: Base is the base class of Derived

typedef msm::back::state_machine<Base>  SM_Base;
typedef msm::back::state_machine<Derived>  SM_Derived;
```

So is `SM_Derived` a subtype of `SM_Base` and I can do all the regular polymorphic operations?

Comment: I read your title 3 times and still don't understand it... The question is much better :)

Comment: @lago I know, i really don't know how to describe this question in a short sentence..

Comment: By the way, this can be answered by how the compiler works. It initially reads your code and replaces all typedefs with their original types and thus continues compiling the code. Thus, if `Derived` originally was a subtype of `Base`, then `SM_Derived` will be a subtype of `SM_Base`

Comment: @lago but when i do `std::weak_ptr<SM_Base> m_sm = sm //(sm is a std::shared_ptr<SM_Derived> )`, the compiler throw error `no match operator =`. why is that?

Comment: Ohh, templates are invariant in C++. I was not remembering that... Sorry :( 
However, there is a trick to overpass this error: http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2015/11/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c.html

Comment: Your question remains unclear, in particular the title and also as it has nothing to do with `typedef` but instead with `template`. You should mention `template` somewhere in the title.

Comment: @Walter If I know it is about `template`, I would say it. How do you expect the patient knows what causes the illness? The patient only describes the symptom

Answer (score 2):

Introducing new names through `typedef` (or `using`) does not influence the relationship between the types.

Thus, the question is whether `msm::back::state_machine<Derived>` is a subtype of `msm::back::state_machine<Base>`.

Which it isn't.

You can also easily check such things with a tiny bit of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_base_of<SM_Base, SM_Derived>::value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No. This property is called [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) and C++ template parameters don't have it (i.e. they are invariant).